# Which mapping does the scenario belong too?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables

`Reservation` and `Driver`

The table definition for `Reservation` table is

```
Reservation(table)
  ReservationId (primary key)
  DriverId (foreign key from table Driver)
  Boarding Point
  Dropping Point
```

The table definition for `Driver` table is

```
Driver(table)
  DriverId (primary key)
  DriverName
```

I wanted to find which mapping does it belong too in hibernate.

How to achieve the above scenario using hibernate annotations.

Comment: I mean... It's basic Hibernate, and you don't provide any clues on what is really difficult for you. Are you trying to make us do your homework?

Comment: How is it possible to make a mapping if reservation id is not avaliable in driver (table). @orion78fr

Comment: I think that in your example, the same driver can have multiple reservations. This means you can't add the reservation id in the driver table. This is a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: From purely the tables it is impossible to tell if it is a one-to-one or a many-to-one.  For example, if this is some kind of taxi service then it makes sense a driver could have multiple reservations and I would think it is a many-to-one.  If could also be mapped as a one-to-one however.  It all depends on whether or not you will ever want to get a list of reservations for a single driver.  If so, it is many-to-one.  If not, it is one-to-one.